# DjangoのManyToManyFieldでthroughを使用していますが、エラーが出て改善方法がわかりません

Tags: python3, ubuntu, django, windows-10, データ構造

Windows10でプログラムを作成し、動作を確認した後、Ubuntu18同じものを書き込んでいます。Windows では正常に作動します。
ManyToManyFieldを入れたmodelまではDBに入るが、中間テーブルのデータは入りません。

Errorは下記になります。

```
AttributeError at/seisan/parts_s_create/
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use seisan.MaterialPartsRelation's Manager instead
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

次のページを見つけました。似たようなエラーが発生しているようです。

- [Django ManyToManyFieldのthrough属性を調べた](https://koty.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/14/000000)

この記事によると、「中間モデルを明示的にcreateする必要があるようです。」とのことでした。

> from datetime import datetime as dt
>   TeamAssign.objects.create(team=teamA, user=scott, enable_from=dt(2018,12, 16))
>   TeamAssign.objects.create(team=teamA, user=tiger, enable_from=dt(2018,12, 17))

参考になるか分かりませんが、よろしくれば確認してみてください。